# How to Set requestSerializer in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, api, afnetworking, alamofire

I am currently working on a project in `swift`. I used `Alamofire` for `REST API`
but to make it work i need to pass a parameter in `requestSerializer`

In `AFNETWORKING`

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

But i can't find anything for `Alamofire`.
I'm new to swift please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass pass `JSON` data as encoding parameters, `Encoding` in `Alamofire` is equivalent to `AFJSONRequestSerializer`

```
request = Alamofire.request(.POST, webServicesURL, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: self.headers)
```

If you want to handle JSON data on response, just request

```
//This will give you response in JSON
request?.responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result
        {
        case .Success:
            success(response: response.result.value)
        case .Failure(let error):
            failure(error: error)
        }
    }
```

`requestJSON` is equivalent to `AFJSONResponseSerializer` in Alamofire

OR If you want to pass custom headers, pass a dictionary as

```
let headers = [
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
]
//Here we are passing the header in header parameter.
request = Alamofire.request(.POST, webServicesURL, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: self.headers)
```

Comment: One more Question`success(response: response.result.value)` is default block of alamofire or it's custom Created By YOU.

Comment: Actually, its all depends upon you, how ever I've written the success block and handle the switch block accordingly

Comment: In the method, where i've written the responseJSON Block has success block, and handling accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can use `encoding` tag in your request for this. Use like,

`Alamofire.request("<url>", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default){(response:DataResponse<Any>) in 
}`