# How to add requestSerializer for Alamofire when posting?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

When using AFNetworking, I did this to custom requestSerializer:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:urlString parameters:parameters progress:nil success:xxxxxx];
```

But, I don't know how to handle this using Alamofire in Swift code.
The only solution I found is

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil)
```

and it comes from the question
[How to Set requestSerializer in Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279260/how-to-set-requestserializer-in-alamofire/38279347).
But it doesn't works. 
The error info is that:

```
Extra argument 'method' in call.
```

And I found some other guy says another method:

```
struct JSONStringArrayEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    private let array: [String]

    init(array: [String]) {
        self.array = array
    }

    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var urlRequest = urlRequest.urlRequest

        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: [])

        if urlRequest?.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
            urlRequest?.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }

        urlRequest?.httpBody = data

        return urlRequest!
    }
}
```

And it also doesn't work, and shows

```
Extra argument 'method' in call.
```

Is there some body help me? Thanks.